# Finite groups with integral character table

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, finite-groups, characters

The character table of a finite group will be called *integral* if all its entries are integers. There are $11$ such groups up to order $16$, namely $C_1$, $C_2$, $C_2^2$, $S_3$, $D_8$, $Q_8$, $C_2^3$, $D_{12}$, $C_2 \times D_8$, $C_2 \times Q_8$ and $C_2^3$. There are $76$ such groups up to order $120$ (see Appendix), the last one of the list, namely $S_5$, is of specific interest as it is the first non-solvable one. In fact, every symmetric group has an integral character table. It can be proved using the following result (Lemma 7.15 in [this note](https://eugeniomaths.files.wordpress.com/2020/07/ghsvrevised12july.pdf) by [Sam Raskin](https://web.ma.utexas.edu/users/sraskin/)):

> **Lemma**: Let $G$ be a finite group such that for all $g \in G$ of order $n$
> and for all $m$ coprime to $n$,  $g^m$ is conjugate to $g$. Then $G$
> has an integral character table.

**Question**: What is known about the finite groups with integral character table? Are they classified?

I mainly ask for references reviewing what is known about such groups. Otherwise here is a list of questions:

- Is the converse of above lemma true?
- I guess that $C_2$ is the only such group which is simple. Is it true?
- I guess that $C_1$ is the only such group of odd order. Is it true?
- Is there such a group with a non-abelian and non-alternating simple normal subgroup?
- Is every finite group a normal subgroup of such a group?

---

**Appendix**: List of all the finite groups with integral character table up to order $120$.

```
gap> for o in [1..120] do
>       if o=1 then Print("\n","|G| ","Nr ","G ","\n","\n");fi;
>       n:=NrSmallGroups(o);;
>       for i in [1..n] do
>               G:=SmallGroup(o,i);;
>               irr:=Irr(G);;
>               s:=Size(irr);;
>               c:=0;;
>               for j in [1..s] do
>                       if Conductor(irr[j])<>1 then
>                               c:=1;;
>                               break;
>                       fi;
>               od;
>               if c=0 then
>                       Print(o,"   ",i,"   ",StructureDescription(G),"\n");
>               fi;
>       od;
> od;

|G| Nr G

1   1   1
2   1   C2
4   2   C2 x C2
6   1   S3
8   3   D8
8   4   Q8
8   5   C2 x C2 x C2
12   4   D12
16   11   C2 x D8
16   12   C2 x Q8
16   14   C2 x C2 x C2 x C2
18   4   (C3 x C3) : C2
24   12   S4
24   14   C2 x C2 x S3
32   27   (C2 x C2 x C2 x C2) : C2
32   34   (C4 x C4) : C2
32   35   C4 : Q8
32   43   C8 : (C2 x C2)
32   44   (C2 x Q8) : C2
32   46   C2 x C2 x D8
32   47   C2 x C2 x Q8
32   49   (C2 x C2 x C2) : (C2 x C2)
32   50   (C2 x Q8) : C2
32   51   C2 x C2 x C2 x C2 x C2
36   10   S3 x S3
36   13   C2 x ((C3 x C3) : C2)
48   38   D8 x S3
48   40   Q8 x S3
48   48   C2 x S4
48   51   C2 x C2 x C2 x S3
54   14   (C3 x C3 x C3) : C2
64   134   ((C4 x C4) : C2) : C2
64   137   (C4 : Q8) : C2
64   138   ((C2 x C2 x C2 x C2) : C2) : C2
64   177   ((C4 x C4) : C2) : C2
64   178   (C4 : Q8) : C2
64   182   C8 : Q8
64   202   C2 x ((C2 x C2 x C2 x C2) : C2)
64   211   C2 x ((C4 x C4) : C2)
64   212   C2 x (C4 : Q8)
64   215   (C2 x C2 x D8) : C2
64   216   (C2 x ((C4 x C2) : C2)) : C2
64   217   ((C4 x C4) : C2) : C2
64   218   (C2 x ((C4 x C2) : C2)) : C2
64   224   ((C2 x Q8) : C2) : C2
64   225   (C4 : Q8) : C2
64   226   D8 x D8
64   230   Q8 x D8
64   239   Q8 x Q8
64   241   ((C4 x C2 x C2) : C2) : C2
64   242   ((C4 x C4) : C2) : C2
64   243   ((C4 x C2 x C2) : C2) : C2
64   244   (C4 : Q8) : C2
64   245   (C2 x C2) . (C2 x C2 x C2 x C2)
64   254   C2 x (C8 : (C2 x C2))
64   255   C2 x ((C2 x Q8) : C2)
64   261   C2 x C2 x C2 x D8
64   262   C2 x C2 x C2 x Q8
64   264   C2 x ((C2 x C2 x C2) : (C2 x C2))
64   265   C2 x ((C2 x Q8) : C2)
64   267   C2 x C2 x C2 x C2 x C2 x C2
72   40   (S3 x S3) : C2
72   41   (C3 x C3) : Q8
72   43   (C3 x A4) : C2
72   46   C2 x S3 x S3
72   49   C2 x C2 x ((C3 x C3) : C2)
96   209   C2 x D8 x S3
96   212   C2 x Q8 x S3
96   226   C2 x C2 x S4
96   227   ((C2 x C2 x C2 x C2) : C3) : C2
96   230   C2 x C2 x C2 x C2 x S3
108   17   ((C3 x C3) : C3) : (C2 x C2)
108   39   ((C3 x C3) : C2) x S3
108   44   C2 x ((C3 x C3 x C3) : C2)
120   34   S5
```

Comment: I think Weyl groups are known to be examples. Using the Weyl group of $E_8$ you get an example with a nonabelian simple normal subgroup that is not an alternating group.

Comment: Answer to your third question: yes $1$ is the only example of odd order. If $G$ has this property and has odd order $\ge 1$, let $C$ be a cyclic subgroup of prime order $p$. Then the normalizer of $C$ is transitive on $C-\{1\}$, so its order is divisible by $p-1$, hence is even. (This also proves that whenever a prime $p$ divides $|G|$, then $p-1$ divides $|G|$.)

Comment: You should be aware that the GAP structure description of a group does not always identify a group up to isomorphism. It would be more informative to print the numbers of the groups of each order.

Comment: @DerekHolt: ok, done!

Comment: @YCor: Then the order of a $\mathbb{Q}$-group must be in https://oeis.org/A124240

Comment: @YCor Yes all the Weyl groups are $\mathbb{Q}$-groups, according to the third line of the introduction of the book of D. Kletzing (cited in Alex answer). The Weyl group of $E_6$ also has a nonabelian simple normal subgroup that is not an alternating group. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E6_(mathematics)#Weyl_group

Comment: My first guess is false, see Corollary B.1 in *On finite rational groups and related topics* by Feit and Seitz: Let $G$ be a noncyclic simple group. Then $G$ has an integral character table iff $G =Sp_6(2)$ or $O_8^+(2)’$.

Comment: https://oeis.org/A064527 *Numbers k such that there exists a finite group G of order k such that all entries in its character table are integers.*

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is no complete classification, but some structural results are known. To give you something to search for: such groups are called $\mathbb{Q}$-groups. There is a whole book devoted to their structure: [Structure and Representations of $\mathbb{Q}$-Groups](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2FBFb0103426) by D. Kletzing. You will find there answers to many, if not all, of your questions.

In particular, the converse of the lemma is indeed true. It follows from two facts: firstly, characters "separate" conjugacy classes, i.e. if two elements are not conjugate, then there exists an irreducible character that takes different values on them; and secondly, if $m$ is coprime to the order of $g$, then for every irreducible character $\chi$ the values $\chi(g)$ and $\chi(g^m)$ are Galois conjugates.

Comment: I found a very strong result in the book your cited (Corollary 12): let $G$ be a $\mathbb{Q}$-group and let $g \in G$, then $ord(g)$ divides $|G|$. In particular, for every prime divisor $p$ of $|G|$ then $p-1$ divides $|G|$. So if $G$ is not trivial then it must be of even order.

Comment: Oh, I've just mentioned this fact above (I didn't know this fact but it's a straightforward observation).

Comment: In my comment above, $ord(g)$ should be replace by $\varphi(ord(g))$, otherwise it is just Lagrange theorem...

Answer (score 7):

It was proved by W. Feit and G. Seitz that there are (at most) five non-Abelian simple groups which are not alternating and may occurs as composition factors of  groups with integral character table (to use your terminology). There is a reference to their paper in the 2008 paper of J.G. Thompson "On composition factors of rational finite groups" ( Journal of Algebra, 319 (2008), 558-594.

In his paper, Thompson proves that if a cyclic group of order $p$ occurs as a composition factor of a rational finite group, then $p \leq 11$, and expresses the belief that the correct bound may be $p \leq 5$.

Work on solvable rational groups has been done by R. Gow, and later by P. Hegedus.

Later edit: A more general supply of rational finite groups than symmetric groups is provided by finite real reflection groups, which usually have all complex characters rational-valued.

Comment: The five non-abelian simple groups mentioned are $PSp_4(3)$, $Sp_6(2)$, $PSL_3(4)$, $PSU_4(3)$, and $\Omega_8^{+}(2)$.